# Why does this program shows an error?

Tags: java, linked-list

I made a function to delete the first element in a doubly linked list. But theres an error in the statement `head.getnext().getprevious()= null;`
Can anyone help?

```
 public DNode deleteFirst()    // deletes the first element.
    {
          if( head== null) // for empty list
          {
              System.out.println("List already Empty!");
          }

            DNode temp = head;
            if (head.getNext()== null)   //if only one item
                tail = null;
            else
               head.getNext().getPrevious()= null;
            head = head.getNext();
            return temp;
              }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? How do you expect to assign a value to the result of a method call?

Comment: I was gonna try to make that particular link null so as to delete that.

Comment: Does that sound like something you want to do on the *result* of a `getPrevious()` call? Surely you're trying to *set* the previous link... so look for a `setPrevious` method...

Comment: I changed it to head.getNext().Setprevious(null); works perfectly. Thankss

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment, but you can not assign a value to a method...

```
       head.getNext().getPrevious()= null;
```

`getPrevious` is returning a a reference to the value, you can't assign a value to the method (or the variable behind it).

Not all methods return a managed variable, some return calculated values, so it makes no sense to allow this type of assignment.

You will need to provide more a method which is capable of actually dereferencing the field contained within the class

Answer (score 0):

The result of the getPrevious method is a copy of the previous attribute of the next element, not a pointer to the field representing the attribute. If you are going to change an attribute, you need a setter as well as a getter: `head.getNext().setPrevious(null);`